# changes to core data managed objects don't get saved

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to save three instances of the core data managed object `"People"`, each has multiple values such as money, name, and profit.

At the moment this doesn't work, there is no data saved.

**Code :**

```
    //In view controller showing data
    //Viewdidload
     let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if results.count > 0{
        var thisUser = results[0] as! People
        labelMoney.text = "\(thisUser.money)"
        labelName.text = "\(thisUser.name)"
        labelProfit.text =  "\(thisUser.profit)"
        if results.count > 1{
            var thisUser = results[1] as! People

        }
        if results.count > 2{
            var thisUser = results[2] as! People

        }

    }

  //In view controller creating name and money
  //in button
  let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", txtUsername.text)

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    if results.count > 0{
        var yes = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
        yes.setValue(money, forKey: "money")
        yes.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    }
 // In game view controller saving data
 //In button
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    var newUser = results[thisPerson] as! People
    newUser.setValue(profit, forKey: "profit")
    newUser.setValue(money, forKey: "money")

    context.save(nil)
```

Comment: "What's the best way" and "fix my code" are kind of broad for Stack Overflow... Please try to sharpen your question.

Comment: Always avoid asking to fix code. More experienced SO users don't like this. Try to list the solutions you already tried and maybe links to other questions like yours but where the solution didn't work. If you started working from a tutorial it is never bad to also post a link to it.

Also try to respond quickly to comments and answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //In view controller showing data
    //Viewdidload
```

declare appDel and your context as class variables. Assign them in viewDidLoad

```
     let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
```

try to name context en request more specific, this will keep your code legible. It will get confusing when you start fetching from more than one entity or when you use more than one type of context (e.g. CGContext)

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

results can also be nil, result.count will then throw an error. How you handle the results is a bit weird, but i am assuming you haven't really written the code yet to handle the results.

```
    if results.count > 0{
        var thisUser = results[0] as! People
        labelMoney.text = "\(thisUser.money)"
        labelName.text = "\(thisUser.name)"
        labelProfit.text =  "\(thisUser.profit)"
        if results.count > 1{
            var thisUser = results[1] as! People

        }
        if results.count > 2{
            var thisUser = results[2] as! People

        }

    }

  //In view controller creating name and money
  //in button
```

this can be deleted if you declare them as class variables instead of declaring them at a local scope

```
  let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
```

Are you fetching already saved data here and assigning updated values?? If not, there is no need for a fetch here. If it is, you should handle it with an if else statement. If there is a person, update values, else create a new person...

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", txtUsername.text)

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    if results.count > 0{
        var yes = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
        yes.setValue(money, forKey: "money")
        yes.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    }
 // In game view controller saving data
 //In button
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "People")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    var newUser = results[thisPerson] as! People
    newUser.setValue(profit, forKey: "profit")
    newUser.setValue(money, forKey: "money")
```

Your naming is confusing here: If it is a new user, it can not be the result of a fetch. A fetch is only used for saved data, so a saved user.

```
    context.save(nil)
```

Creating a new User:

```
var newUser =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: context!) as! People
newUser.profit = 42
newUser.money = 1984

context.save()
```

**Recap :**

- Try to improve your naming
- Fetches are only used to alter/display/use existing saved data that is not yet loaded. If you just created a new instance, there is no need to fetch, it is still there.
- Creating a new instance is done with the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` method. Assign the values you want to it and save.
- Also look into resetting the Managed Object Context. Or releasing loaded/recently saved data. This will prevent changes to to your instances when you save something else.
- Also look at viewWillDisappear and willGoToBackground methods to automatically save your data when your app goes to the background or you segue away from a view.